# Unity - my camera moves when play move is actived

Tags: unity-game-engine

My camera has a perfect position in my scene. When I hit the "play" button, it moves back. I assum the problem is in my camera script but I can't find it. Here is my camera script :

[camera script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTuft.png)

Obviously the script is attached to the camera, and the player parameter is link to the player object.
Any ideas ? Looks like the offset is miscalculated..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to subtract the player's position when you calculated the offset. Should be like this:

```
void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}
```